# How to obtain the derivative of a conjugated quaternion?

Tags: quaternions, derivative

I'm currently currently stuck at obtaining the derivative of a pure yaw conjugated quaternion, what I mean by this is the following:

[image: Quaternion conjugate derivative]

The previous image is my attempt at finding the answer. However, this my first time studying quaternions and I haven't found the literal expression of the derivative of a conjugated quaternion in any book (not even the Quaternion hand-book), so I'm thinking it must be trivial but still want to confirm if I'm right or wrong. Any guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The derivative of a conjugate unit quaternion in terms of quaternions can be easily derived as follows using the product rule. Start with this identity using the fact that q* = inv(q) for unit quaternions:

q x q* = 1        <-- where 1 is the identity quaternion, and x is quaternion multiply

And then take the derivative of both sides and solve for what you want:

(d/dt) (q x q*) = (d/dt) 1

(d/dt)q x q* + q x (d/dt)q* = 0

q x (d/dt)q* = -(d/dt)q x q*

(d/dt)q* = - q* x (d/dt)q x q*

Your hand derivation in your post is almost correct. You can certainly start with the elements of the quaternion in question and simply do the element-wise derivatives, but you forgot to include the derivative of the arguments per the chain rule. That is, you need to multiply your answer by psidot/2, but you only have the 1/2 part of that in your equation. You need to multiply what you have written by psidot.